# Combobox Css Ajuda

Tags: css

Alguém me pode ensinar como consigo meter aquela seta com aquele tracejado ao lado ?

[image: Exemplo da combobox]

Comment: Sugiro a leitura de [ask]. Faltam detalhes e mais objetividade na sua pergunta.

Comment: esse "tracejado" dessa borda provavelmente é uma imagem como borda, pois o tracejado normal do CSS não consegue ser tão comprimido como esse, que até parece ser apenas uma linha vendo assim pela imagem que adicionas-te à pergunta. Mas se partilhares o link de onde viste essa borda, pode-se confirmar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir estilizar o Combobox, a primeira coisa a fazer remover todo o estilo do mesmo, então envolver o mesmo em uma div, e estilizar esta div.

É necessário estilizar a DIV no lugar do select, uma vez que o select em si não suporta muitos recursos do CSS em si.

```css
/* Removendo stilos do Select */
.select-com-estilo select {  
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 0px none transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* diga olá para o IE */
.select-com-estilo select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

/* Setando o tamanho do Select - fica ao seu criterio */
.select-com-estilo select {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 32px; /* largura da imagem (24px), acredito da "margem a direita" (olhar background-position no estilo abaixo)(4px) e da "margem a esquerda"(4px) */
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 32px;
}

/* A imagem abaixo possui tamanho 24px por 24px */
.select-com-estilo {    
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: whitesmoke;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAA5klEQVRIS92V4Q3CIBCF6QQ6ihuokxgncAXdwBHcpLqBo+gGvtfkEsQD7s70T5u8tCnh++CAdkgzX8PM/LQswRrlOiGXP8t2Rv8r8iJHSkT4iGyQG3IMStj3gDyRPSUU5HDhRiQCF8YkoeCObJUReyQlXHAPClgWSlZBSQ3+Bm8naxCVNOFci/wceCVdOCtSHjSrxATXBHzXk3BQ3IrlNdWcZckbap+KlkRhJxVem4EArJIqvCfolYvtTbhF0JJ04VaBJjHBPYJcwuef3aKtvFcgEt6/tmINHhG0WGrbsn6Z7ulbOnwAN0E5GbS/JDkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 4px); /* "margem a direita" de 4px */
}
```

```html
<div class="select-com-estilo">
   <select>
      <option>Primeira Opção</option>
      <option>Segunda Opção</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Para deixar o select como deseja, vai precisar apenas substituir a imagem por uma imagem igual ao do seu exemplo.

Segue a fonte da imagem usada no Exemplo: [Flaticons - Down arrow of angle](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/down-arrow-of-angle_60926)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.sidebar-right {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
div.name-user {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.options {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px dashed #C7C7C7;
  border-left: 2px solid #C7C7C7;
  height: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.options:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-right">
  <div class="name-user">Administrador</div>
  <div class="options"></div>
</div>
```